# proving if this is a valid pmf

Tags: probability-theory, combinations

I am trying to check if the pmf is valid and i reached this point and could not go further. is there a way get 1 (proving that it is valid). 
$$ \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2\left(n-i\right)}{n-i}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any real $ \alpha $ : $$ \left(\forall x\in\left]-1,1\right[\right),\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\binom{\alpha}{n}x^{n}}=\left(1+x\right)^{\alpha} $$

Thus, for $ x\in\left]-1,1\right[ $ : $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}x^{n}}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} \ \ \ \ \left(*\right) $$

Observe that : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}=\displaystyle\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{n}n!}\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(2k+1\right)}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4^{n}}\displaystyle\binom{2n}{n} $$

Multiplying the expression $ \left(*\right) $ by itself gives the following : $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{4^{n}}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\displaystyle\binom{2k}{k}\displaystyle\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}\right)x^{n}}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x^{n}} $$

Hence : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \frac{1}{4^{n}}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\displaystyle\binom{2k}{k}\displaystyle\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}=1 $$

Comment: thanks for the response, one more question, when were multiply (∗) by itself x^n remains the same?

Comment: @Cleo to multiply two power series together, we must use Cauchy's product. That's what I did. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Definitions

Comment: thank you for the clarification, now i understand